# Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, config

I have a problem when I run a project react native CLI,
**this is: **
Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat tasks FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'NiceTest'. > Could not determine the dependencies of null. > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:. Required by: project : > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin. Required by: project : > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but: - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library, packaged as a jar, and
its dependencies declared externally: - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8 - Other compatible attribute: - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1') - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally: - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer
needed a library - Other compatible attributes: - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8) - Doesn't say
anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar) - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1') - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime) - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares
a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally: - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8 - Other compatible attribute: - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1') - Variant 'testResultsElementsForTest' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified:

- Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library - Other compatible attributes: - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally) - Doesn't say anything about its target Java
  version (required compatibility with Java 8) - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar) - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1') - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime) * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 7s.

I tried many time to config it, but can not solve. After that i have config my jdk, and i see my jdk ver and javac ver difference, so i fixed it on screens:
[screen jdk & javac ver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWdcQ.png)
I hope anyone help me to finish my project

Comment: Any update on this? We have been trying to get this to work on Windows and getting the same exact error. We followed every single step exactly and have tried so many different things.